# How i compile and run erlang program?

Tags: erlang

i have

1. freebsd 10
2. folder **/usr/home/ec2-user/ezmq** with files from **https://github.com/zeromq/ezmq**
3. installed erlang

then i:

1. in command line run - erl
2. in erl

   c("/usr/home/ec2-user/ezmq/examples/hwclient.erl").

   c("/usr/home/ec2-user/ezmq/examples/hwserver.erl").
3. hwserver:main().
4. hwclient:main().

and have error

exception error: undefined function ezmq:start/1
     in function  hwserver:main/0 (/usr/home/ec2-user/ezmq/examples/hwserver.erl, line 14)

and have error

exception error: undefined function ezmq:start/1 in function  hwclient:main/0 (/usr/home/ec2-user/ezmq/examples/hwclient.erl, line 14)

how i compile and run

this https://github.com/zeromq/ezmq/blob/master/examples/hwclient.erl + hwserver.erl

examples?

and i have error

```
** exception exit: {{undef,[{gen_listener_tcp,start_link,
                                              [ezmq_tcp_socket, 
                                               [<0.49.0>,<<>>,5555,
                                                [binary,inet,
                                                 {active,false},
                                                 {send_timeout,5000},
                                                 {backlog,10},
                                                 {nodelay,true},
                                                 {packet,raw},
                                                 {reuseaddr,true}]],
                                               []],
                                              []},
                            {ezmq,handle_call,3,[{file,"src/ezmq.erl"},{line,238}]},
                            {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                                        [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,585}]},
                            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                      [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]},
                    {gen_server,call,[<0.49.0>,{bind,tcp,5555,[]}]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 180)
     in call from hwserver:main/0 (/usr/home/ec2-user/ezmq/examples/hwserver.erl, line 15)
```

Comment: Did you install the ZMQ files with rebar or just directly from GitHub?

Comment: i run git clone https://github.com/zeromq/ezmq.git

Answer (score 4):

This project uses rebar, so try this:

1. Download it from here: https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki/rebar
2. Make it executable
3. Compile: `./rebar compile`
4. Open two terminals
5. In terminal 1, run: `erl -pa ebin -pa /deps/gen_listener_tcp/ebin`
   The `-pa` option tells the vm where to load beam files from.

   1. In the erlang shell, run:

      `c("examples/hwserver")
      hwserver:main().`
6. In terminal 2, run: `erl -pa ebin -pa /deps/gen_listener_tcp/ebin`

   1. In the erlang shell, run:

      `c("examples/hwclient")
      hwclient:main().`

You should see a bunch of output.

The make file seems to require putting `rebar` in your path. Once you do that, you can try the make targets.

Comment: i do it. how i run hwclient.erl + hwserver.erl

Comment: When you run `erl -pa ebin`, it should bring up a shell. You should be able to run the server and client mains from that shell.

Comment: i run in erlang shell hwserver:main(). and have error ** exception error: undefined function hwserver:main/0

Comment: I guess the example isn't compiled with the rebar compile. I'll look at it more closely soon.

Comment: Check the updated answer, I tried the whole process and it worked for me.